# How do I prevent my cursor from changing fields when loading websites?

Tags: google-chrome, cursor, user-experience

I often start typing into a text field on a website before the website has loaded completely, for example to log into Gmail while the login screen is loading, to log into my banking website, etc.

Often when I do this, the cursor will move to a different field once the website has completed loading, e.g. on Gmail it will move to the password field.

The effect of this is that I may inadvertently be typing into the wrong field without realising, ending up with a portion of the text in the correct field and the remaining text in the wrong field, forcing me to start over, e.g. having to retype my username, which seems an unnecessary waste of time.

Why does this happen and how can I prevent this from happening?

I am using Google Chrome on Windows 7 and on Windows Vista.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Your collective suggestion works thus far but takes some getting used to. I am going to leave the question open for another day in the hopes of finding a more permanent solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of people blame the mouse settings for this, I'm pretty sure it's because as the website is still loading when you are typing, a script will move the cursor to a specific text box (usually their search engine). To get around this, as soon as the page comes on and you can see where you want to type, click the 'X' icon at top toolbar and it will stop it loading any more, (the icon changes to a refresh icon if the page is fully loaded).  You can then click into your text box any type without interruption.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be working for now. Pressing ESC is a keyboard short cut for the stop loading instruction. I did not know this but Googled a keyboard short cut to your suggestion. I am going to leave the question open for a day or two to attract other suggestions. I was actually hoping that it would be possible to change a setting somewhere to permanently fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the implications of browser skipping over to the next text field in a web page may be out of scope for SU but could be answered by somebody more savvy over server fault.

As to adress your issue you may either try

1)Stop loading the page by hitting the <kbd>esc</kbd> and then enter the values.
or

2)Use a password manager like [Lastpass](https://lastpass.com/index.php?fromwebsite=1) and overcome the need to enter the values into text fields each time the 
webpage loads.